# In CRM Dynamics 2015, How can I redirect to an External Website or External Desktop client?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2015

Hi I am new to CRM an I wonder if there is a way to navigate to an external URL or application and how can I go about it. Also is is possible to override the Skype/Lync client click-to-call with a different telephony client installed on my machine, for example Zoiper,. If the user clicks the phone number on a contact entity, I want to redirect to either the despot client or web client to display the Zoiper dialing system, any ideas of how I can archive this in CRM Dynamics 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sitemap allows for external links [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309259.aspx#BKMK_ConfigurationOptions).

```
<SubArea 
 AvailableOffline=["0" | "1" | "true" | "false"]
 CheckExtensionProperty="String"
 Client=["All" | "Outlook" | "OutlookLaptopClient" | "OutlookWorkstationClient"  | "Web" ]
 Description="String"
 DescriptionResourceId="String"
 Entity="String"
 GetStartedPanePath="String"
 GetStartedPanePathAdmin="String"
 GetStartedPanePathAdminOutlook="String"
 GetStartedPanePathOutlook="String"
 Icon="String"
 Id="String"
 License="String"
 OutlookShortcutIcon="String"
 PassParams=["0" | "1" | "true" | "false"]
 ResourceId="String"
 Sku=["All" | "OnPremise" | "Live" | "SPLA"]
 Title="String"
 Url="String"> ←------------ this is where the ext. url is specified
 <Titles />
 <Descriptions />
 <Privilege/>
</SubArea>
```

About the other point, AFAIK Click-To-Call is handled by a browser extension so the CRM cant'do much about it. Lync presence OTOH is handled by CRM through AD, and isn't customizable without risking losing the platform.

Comment: With regards to launching the Desktop client from CRM dynamics ,how do I launch the desktop client,for the web I would use the url, I had an idea of using a WCF Service that launches the Zoiper desktop client and then use the SiteMap action Javascript capabilities to call that service using Jquery, would this be the best way or is therw another way to approach it from a CRM dynamics 2015 perspective?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I suggest you make that a new question.